# Merge Publication Data Partition Snapshot generation

Tags: sql-server-2008, snapshot, merge-replication

I have a merge publication in SQL 2008 R2 with data partitions and I am wondering when I should generate the snapshots for the data partitions.  I get an error sometimes when bringing a new subscribe online related to the partition snapshot being out of date and I am wondering if this has to do with the publication snapshot being scheduled at the same time as the partition snapshots.  I'm not really sure how the partition snapshot gets generated, but it appears maybe it is getting generated before the publication snapshot.

If this is the case how should I be scheduling the partition snapshots to get generated?  Should I set them to run x number of minutes after the publication snapshot? this seems kind of poor to do in case the publication snapshot takes awhile or fails.  It seems to me the publication snapshot should just run the data partition snapshot agents when it is done if this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

When you bring new subscribers online you'll need to run the snapshot agent, so that a new snapshot can be generated which is then used to populate the new subscriber.

Comment: This doesn't do much to answer my question.  My question has to do with scheduling the publication snapshot and then the data partition snapshots. I assume the data partition snapshots need to run after the publication snapshot, so I'm trying to figure out how to best tie them together.  it appears that in some cases my data partition snapshots are running before the partition snapshot and I am thinking that is why I get the error.

Comment: Typically you don't need to schedule the replication snapshot agent to run on a regular basic.  I'm not clear as to why it's being run if you aren't adding a subscriber.